# How to prevent Windows from accessing a directory inside a share?

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, group-policy

At work, domain group policy is set to display a background image located in a shared folder. The path is similar to:

```
\\example\gpo\desktop.jpg
```

The image is ugly and distracting. Unfortunately, group policy prevents users from changing the background.

Is there a way, in Windows 7 Professional, to block access to either `\\example\gpo\desktop.jpg` or `\\example\gpo`, so that it couldn't show the image, resulting in a flat background?

Note that:

- Blocking the whole `\\example` is not an option, since I need to access `\\example\something-else`.
- I'm denied to change file permissions of the shared directory or the image (I tried to deny read access to myself, but unsuccessfully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, changing local group policy works. I'm not sure why, since the domain group policy is expected to overwrite the local one, but still, the image imposed by the domain policy is not here any longer after a reboot.

In `gpedit.msc`, go to:

1. Local Computer Policy
2. user Configuration
3. Administrative Templates
4. Desktop
5. Desktop

Set *Desktop Wallpaper* to *Enabled* ans specify an alternative image in *Wallpaper Name*.